# Write a R function to find binary subset

Tags: r

I have a binary vector x=(1,0,0,1). lower-order terms including itself of this vectors are assumed (0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1), (1,0,0,0) and (1,0,0,1). How do I find this lower-order vectors in R.

What I understand so far: basically we want o find subsets, replace each 1 by 0. But to do it in R? I am clueless?

here what I tried so far.

```r
a<-c(1,0,0,1)
M<-length(a)

for(i in 1:M){
  
  ifelse(a[i]==1, a[i]<-0, next)
  print(a)
  
  }
[1] 0 0 0 1
[1] 0 0 0 0
```

what I am looking for in detail: for example, I have 4 factors A,B,C,D. Here (1,0,0,1) means AD.

Now I want a subset of (1,0,0,1) that means AD. In my subsets, I can not have B and C. Result will be  {} {A} {D} {AD} in binary form (0,0,0,0), (1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a method relying on `expand.grid` to do the heavy lifting:

```
vecs = lapply(a, seq, 0)   # keep 0s as 0, make 1s c(1, 0)
do.call(expand.grid, vecs) # generate all combinations
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1    1    0    0    1
# 2    0    0    0    1
# 3    1    0    0    0
# 4    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: how do you change the column names of your output?

Comment: It's a data frame, so anything that works for a data frame works for this. You can use `names(result) = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')`, `setNames(result, ...)`, `colnames(result) = ...`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral`.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
A <- t(apply(permuteGeneral(length(a), sum(a)), 1, function(x) {a[x] <- 0; a}))
A[!duplicated(A), ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `which`, `combn`, and `*apply` functions to perform this operation. Since this is a step-by-step operation, it may be helpful to look at the results line-by-line.

Here it is wrapped in a function called `find_binary_subsets`:

```
find_binary_subsets <- function(x){
  # where does x equal 1
  x_eq_1 <- which(x == 1)
  # combinations of indexes where x == 1
  l_w_x <- lapply(length(x_eq_1):1, 
                  FUN = function(l) combn(x_eq_1, l))
  # loop over the combinations of indexes where x == 1, replace by 0, return vector
  # apply(., 2) loops over the columns of a matrix, which is what we want
  combs <- lapply(l_w_x, 
                  FUN = function(d) 
                    apply(d, 2, FUN = function(i){x[i] <- 0; x}))  
  # cbind results, then transpose to arrange by row
  t(cbind(do.call("cbind", combs), x))
}

find_binary_subsets(a)

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
     0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    1
     1    0    0    0
x    1    0    0    1
```

Comment: Firstly, row 2 and 3 are repetitive. I can not have a repetitive row in my output. here, what I am looking for in details: for example, I have 4 factors A,B,C,D. (1,0,0,1) means AD. 

Now I want a subset of (1,0,0,1) that means AD. In my subsets, I can not have B and C. Result will be  {} {A} {D} {AD} in binary form (0,0,0,0), (1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1).

Comment: Edited my answer to arrange by row instead.